# Authorize.net CIM Rails implementation sample code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

Authorize.net provides some sample code for using CIM with ruby but its uses XML. I am would like to do this with a more rails like method similar to the following AIM transaction code provided by authorize.net

```
transaction = AuthorizeNet::AIM::Transaction.new(API_LOGIN_ID, TRANSACTION_KEY, :gateway =>  :sandbox)
credit_card = AuthorizeNet::CreditCard.new('4111111111111111', '1120')
response = transaction.authorize(bid.amount, credit_card)
```

I have searched but cannot find any sample code. Can anyone please provide a link or some sample code to create a customer, store a creditcard, retrieve the customer and edit?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the ActiveMerchant gem it has a gateway to CIM.

http://activemerchant.org/

Answer (score 0):

CIM API provides two formats: 
-  XML calls
- SOAP calls

I've show a simple example of SOAP call for creating a customer profiles via CIM api methods.I've used SAVON for making soap client.

1.Initialize savon client object with wsdl file for CIM service provided by gateway

client = Savon.client(wsdl: "https://apitest.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx?WSDL",ssl_verify_mode: :none)

2. Make a call with transaction ID provided by gateway

response = client.call(:create_customer_profile,:message => {:merchantAuthentication => {"name" => "-----------","transactionKey" => '-----------'},:profile =>  {:email =>"arunsharmar321@gmail.com"} })

3. Parse response as json output

JSON.parse((response.body).to_json)

Response output in json
=> {"create_customer_profile_response"=>{"create_customer_profile_result"=>{"result_code"=>"Ok", "messages"=>{"messages_type_message"=>{"code"=>"I00001", "text"=>"Successful."}}, "customer_profile_id"=>"36538428", "customer_payment_profile_id_list"=>nil, "customer_shipping_address_id_list"=>nil, "validation_direct_response_list"=>nil}, "@xmlns"=>"https://api.authorize.net/soap/v1/"}}